# problem with enctype="multipart/form-data" in submitting mixed content (files and text)

Tags: php, submit, wampserver, mixed-content

i have problem with enctype="multipart/form-data".

```
<form action="insert_data_script.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <!-- FILE INPUT -->

  <input type="file" name="fileInputName" id="fileToUpload"> 

  <!-- TEXT INPUT -->

  field 1 :<input type="text" name=text-1>

  field 2 :<input type="text" name=text-2>

  
  <input type="submit" value="send" name="submit">
```

What happens with me is this:

when i delete `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, the submit of text inputs (`text-1,text-2`)
run successfully, and the submit of the file fails!.

when i keep `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.the opposite case happens:
the submit of text inputs fails, and the submit of the file run successfully!

Any idea what's going on???

and how to fix it??

i am using :*windows 7 64bits, firefox developper 85.0.2 64bits wampserver2.5-64bits/Apache-2.4.9/Mysql-5.6.17/php5.5.12/*

Comment: <input type="text" name=text-1> Should not the name be wrapped  name='text-1'

Comment: As pointed out by @ZappsCeo, the input fields have a syntax problem, you need to wrap quotes around the value.

Comment: it's tested, with quotes or without quotes is the same.

Comment: @ZappsCeo Quoting the value is not compulsary. [See HTML Attrinutes](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/syntax.html#syntax-attributes)

Comment: `wampserver2.5` ? That could use a bit of an upgrade, but its not the reason for your problem

Comment: Do you actually have a `</form>` tag?

Comment: Ok, you must have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the `<form>` tag for file upload to work. It makes little sense that when thats there you dont get the normal fields sent as well. First try sending a very small file, then with the file that causes an issue, run script and check the Error logs in `wamp\logs\php_error.log`